# Backbone.js - Getting values in template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I have got a Json from the collections by calling the APIs.

```
{
  "next_page_link": null,
  "prev_page_link": null,
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "public": true,
      "actor": {
        "displayName": "Srikanth Jeeva",
        "id": "28"
      }
   },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "public": true,
    "actor": {
      "displayName": "Srikanth jeeva",
      "id": "21"
    }
 }] 
}
```

This is the Views:

```
Raffler.Views.StreamsIndex = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: JST['streams/index'],
    initialize: function(){
        this.collection.on('reset',this.render, this);
    },

    render: function(){
       $(this.el).html(this.template({entries: this.collection}));
       return this;
   }
});
```

Now how do i get these entries in Template?

```
<h1>Stream</h1>
<%= entries["posts"] %>
```

entries["posts"] doesn't display the posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cycle the array and you can use javascript code inside your template using the <% %> tags.

An example could be:

```
<ul>
<% _.each(entries.posts,function(post){ %>
    <li><%= post.actor.displayName %><li>
<% }); %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not sure why, Its not displaying the posts. but it displays <h1>Stream</h1>

Comment: Well passing `this.collection` to the template would do nothing since it is a Backbone.Collection object, and you need just the attributes. You could try with `this.collection.toJSON()` which would create an object containing the attributes of each model inside the collection, you can read more [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON)

Comment: That didnt work as well. May be the Ajax call finishes only after the page loads.

Comment: Well you can try to log in console this.collection.toJSON() in your view's initialize function to check what it returns.

Comment: Oh! its an empty array. But the Ajax call returns data. I think i have to use Model instead of Collection to fetch the data, since my Ajax call is not returning an array.

Comment: Oh, when i use model it returns empty object!

Comment: Cool. The problem is template is rendered before the ajax call completes. I have added this.collection.on('sync', callback) and things works :) Thanks!

Comment: No proble, I'm glad you find the problem :)